# OpenCV getRectSubPix: Why its formula uses (dst.cols - 1) * 0.5?

Tags: opencv, formula

In their documentations:
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#getrectsubpix

the formula is:

```
dst(x, y) = src(x + center.x - ( dst.cols -1)*0.5, y +  center.y - ( dst.rows -1)*0.5)
```

But why do we need to use (dst.cols - 1)?
I think we should directly use dst.cols, and dst.rows.

Answer (score 1):

It is because *position* is 0-based.

Consider what will happen when `dest_cols == 9`. Using the formula, its center is at 4 which is correct. Using your version, its center is at 4.5, incorrect.

Now consider what will happen when `dest_cols == 10`. Using the formula, its center is at 4.5 which is correct. Using your version, its center is at 5, incorrect.

Comment: The coordinates are floating point values. So suppose dest_cols = 9, then the center is 4.5. The center pixel is Number 4 pixel. But in openCV warpAffine, all are floating point values. For the function "getRotationMatrix2D", you could see that they do not do any change to the variable center .

Comment: No, when `dest_cols == 9` the center is at 4. Four columns to its left are columns 0..3 and four columns to its right are columns 5..8. When `dest_cols == 10` the center is at 4.5, five columns to its left are columns 0..4 and five columns to its right are columns 5..9. `getRotationMatrix2D()` works on positions, not sizes.

Comment: I think you are confusing size and position. Just as a rectangle of width 9 has pixel indexes 0..8, half the rectangle width does *not* equate to the rectangle center.